# Kentico 9 - Integrating HTML PDF reader

Tags: html, iframe, kentico

I would like to integrate a HTML code from Calaméo (PDF reader) under Kentico 9. When I copy paste the code, we can not see the PDF reader on the site. I noticed that the code changes when I save the page. The code changes from this :

to this

A "/" disappears. Is it possible that the problem comes from this change ?

I have already integrated a similar code a few month ago with Kentico 8, and it worked and still works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pasting the code into a static HTML webpart?  If you click on the arrow next to the text field, it will open a modal, you can paste your code there and Kentico won't change any of it.

Comment: Great ! Thank you !